# Close Conductor Window from screen

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a ViewModel called WindowViewModel, which inherits from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`. From this ViewModel, I open ChildView (with `WindowManager.ShowWindow(ChildViewModelInstance)`). What I want to do is to close the WindowView from ChildViewModel.

this is my WindowViewModel:

```
public class WindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive,  IHandle<bool>
{
    public WindowViewModel()
    {

    }

    public void OpenChildView()
    { 
       //some code
    } 

    public void CloseItem(Screen item)
    {
        item.TryClose();
        if (Items.Count == 0)
            TryClose();
    }

    public void Handle(bool message)
    {
       //for some reason this isn't handled
       TryClose();
    }
}
```

And this is my ChildViewModel:

```
public class ChildViewModel : Screen
{
    public ChildViewModel()
    {
      //getting eventaggregator...
    }

    public void CloseWindow()
    {
       eventAgregator.PublishOnUIThread(true);
    }
}
```

ChildView is the tabItem of the tabcontrol in WindowView. When I press `x` on the specific tabItem header (and if there is only one tabitem), The WindowView closes (because closeitem is called).

I have tried `PublishOnCurrentThread` and `PublishOnbackgroundThread` instead of `PublishOnUIThread`, but They don't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the `WindowViewModel` with an `IEventAggregator` and subscribe to it by calling its Subscribe method:

```
public class WindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<bool>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

     public void Handle(bool message)
     {
         TryClose();
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: I made some changes in code, and as I found I forgot to write _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);